# How to initialize the filter of a table just after the loading of the page

Tags: footable

I use the excellent plugin "footable" to order and filter my tables.

But in some cases, my page must be initialized with a certain filter. For example, my URL is:

```
myurl/mypage/19
```

On the server side I get the '19' and send it to the view. Into the view I put this value into an input field.

How to filter this table with this input value just after the page is loaded?

I tried:

```
$('table').footable();
$('table').trigger('footable_redraw');
```

and

```
$('table').footable();
$('table').trigger('footable_initialize');
```

Without success.

### Update

I specify that the filter works. It's just that the filter does not initialize when I put something in the field during the load of the page.

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('table').footable();
    $('table').trigger('footable_initialize');
})
```

The HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control" id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher ..." value="{{ $libelle_classe }}">

<table class="table footable table-hover table-bordered"  data-filter="#filter">
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to put your code inside `$(document).ready()` event? https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: sure , the code is inside $(document).ready(). Like that : $(document).ready( function() {
 
 $('table').footable();
 $('table').trigger('footable_initialize');

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to filter table?

Comment: I edited the post with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is trigger the filter event manually, using the input value:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('table').trigger('footable_filter', {
        filter: $("#filter").val()
   });
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it works fine with your solution. I did not know we can filter like that. I love "footable". Merci.

Comment: The filter event in `footable.filter.js` is called when keyup event of input is fired. This does not happens when input value is assigned directly. I like "footable" too, is an awesome plugin!